# SSH to multiple Raspberry PI 4B

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-4, connection

I have 2 PI that are connected to my local network first PI has the IP: `192.168.1.48` and the second one `192.168.1.49` that I can SSH to them in my local network without a problem, however I opened a forward port for the first one, so i can SSH to it remotely now I do SSH to it using my `ssh pi@public ip`, now I need to know how can I SSH to my second PI? if I do forward the port 22 also for the second one, the 2 pi's will be the same IP and port! what can i do in this situation?

Comment: use a different port on the WAN side, and when connecting to it, use the `-p` command line argument for ssh - e.g. use port 2222 WAN -> port 22 on the other pi in the port forward, and then `ssh po@publicIP -p 2222` - how you do this depends on your router, but any decent router allows mapping ports like this, i.e. from and to port don't have to be the same - if your router doesn't allow that, then you'll need to set the listening port on the other pi to, say, 2222, and forward port 2222 -> 2222

Comment: @JaromandaX but the port 22 is for ssh, how can i change the port on the pi?

Comment: well, you won't have to if you redirect 2222 => 22 ... but if your router doesn't allow this, then you configure sshd to listen on port 2222

Answer (score 2):

You could ssh onto the first pi as you do now and from that one ssh into the second one. This would expose fewer ports to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

SSH has a really cool "jump host" option; basically, it allows you to jump through to another host on the network:

```
 -J destination
         Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be specified sep‐
         arated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.  Note that configuration directives supplied on the command-line generally apply to the destination host and not any specified
         jump hosts.  Use ~/.ssh/config to specify configuration for jump hosts.
```

In your case, try something like this: `ssh -J pi@public_ip pi@192.168.1.49`

The command above will access the second pi by jumping through the publicly-accessible one.

Alternatively, I would look into setting up OpenVPN or Wireguard to access your entire private network rather than just the Pis themselves.  It'll make your setup cleaner in the long run.  :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the way. This should be accepted.